# When is someone responsible for a lack of justification and/or strong belief in something?

Tags: knowledge

When is someone responsible for a lack of justification and/or strong belief in something? Suppose I suspect that my wide is cheating on me, and have evidence that she is meeting someone, but aside from that it's just a hunch and some hints. In that case, am I to blame for not knowing about her infidelity? No-one has told me and I've tried.

Comment: Hi. You might or might not be interested in these related questions: [Is there a valid argument for a moral imperative to seek knowledge?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/38096/is-there-a-valid-argument-for-a-moral-imperative-to-seek-knowledge); [When is someone culpable for being tricked?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/102788/when-is-someone-culpable-for-being-tricked) and [All questions about "blaming the victim"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=blaming%20the%20victim)

Comment: thanks for the comment @Stef